# Python Scapy output to txt file

Tags: python-2.7, networking, scapy, packet-sniffers

**I would like to output just IP.dst to txt file, But I get all the packet info including Ether, src, etc**

```
from scapy.all import *
import time
import os
file = open("newfile.txt","w")
t = '%IP.dst%'
p = sniff(filter="ip", prn=lambda x:x.sprintf(t), count=10)
file.write(str(p))
time.sleep(1)
os.system("cls")
```

**Sample output of txt file**

> Ether  dst=f4:ce:46:5c:bf:f8 src=30:10:b3:24:63:b6 type=0x800 /|IP  version=4L ihl=5L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TeckSupport how about if you set up a function that pulls and writes the IP.dst:

```
from scapy.all import *

fob = open("IP.txt","w")

def ip_dst(pkt):
        fob.write(pkt[IP].dst+'\n')

sniff(filter='ip',count=10,prn=ip_dst)
fob.close()
```

Is this what you were looking to do?